# How to increase BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE when using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, buildx

When building a project with docker-compose, after a while I get

```
[output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]
```

From https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/484#issuecomment-812997137, I learned that the log size limit can be altered with `BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE` when creating a buildx builder, but how can I set it in `docker-compose.yml`? Setting it in args or environment doesn't seem to work.

I know I can disable BuildKit as a workaround: `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=0 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build`

Comment: I'd be interested, if you found a solution yet :)

Comment: `export BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=-1`
This command set unlimited log output size